# creating label on uitablview cell in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I am new to iPhone devlopemnt I am developing one app. In that app I need show list items with their respective prices in an `UITableView`. To solve this problem I am following some concept like creating label dynamically in `UITableViewCell` to show the items and their prices.

In app the first `indexid == 1` means that I am showing list places on click of particular cell on list am geting list of favorite items with prices that means indexid = 2 ...on click of back button indexid = 1 then i need hide that label ...but label is not hideing it show list prices not list of items

```
lblText.text = nil;
btnBack.hidden = FALSE;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{     
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
     cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

}

    /////////////////////   Cell Title    /////////////////////
    if (indexId == 1) 
    {
//        NSLog(@"%@",lblText1);
       cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [test.arrTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 7, 40, 30)]; // For right alignment
        lblText.text = [test.arrId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [lblText setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        lblText.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lblText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell addSubview:lblText];

       cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"products-category-bg.png"]];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [lblText release];

    }
    else
    {
        lblText.hidden = YES;
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", [test.arrTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];        

            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"product-bg-hover.png"]];
    }       
    return cell;
}
```

I have the following problem. The label is creating ok, but after on click of back button, I get label values in main tableview.

How can I release the label object with data ?

thanks & regards

Please help me out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, just replace one line in above code with the link written below

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblText];
```

Instead

```
[cell addSubview:lblText];
```

Hope It will resolve your issue.

Comment: thanq for quick replay ..but  am get same error ...that is label on uiatblview first cell only display prices..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same table view instance for the different states in your application you're also re-using cells that were created previously:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

With each cell, when the `indexid == 1` you're also doing this:

```
[cell addSubview:lblText];
```

To me, this says that each cell you've created (and that will be re-used) has a `UILabel` added as a subview. To truly re-use that cell you need to remove that `UILabel` before your logic says that you need to add it again. Not only will this remove the cells when you don't need them, it will also prevent you from adding extra UILabel instances to the cell at runtime. Try adding the code below before you check `indexid`

```
if (cell == nil)
{     
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
     cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}

// Be sure to remove the UILabels on the re-used cell.
for(UIView *view in cell.subviews)
    if ([view isKindOfClass:([UILabel class])])
        [view removeFromSuperview];

if (indexid == 1) { ....
```

This will remove the UILabel each time the cell is created allowing you to conditionally re-added it as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a tag to your label(will help you to set data to labels, you can get the label by calling

> [cell viewWithTag:`theLabelTag`]

where `theLabelTag` tag can be the index) 
and set the label value in

```
tableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:
```

instead of

> tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: